# Terminaison en « s » absente à l'impératif mais liaison induite

Tags: prononciation, conjugaison, liaisons, impératif

Je suis Français et je trouve que ces exemples sonnent très bien avec une liaison [z] :

- *Parle en* à…
- *Pense y.*

Est-ce que ce sont des pataquès ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Des générations de francophones sont d'accord avec toi. Les verbes du premier groupe forment leur impératif présent deuxième personne du singulier en `-e` et non `-es` comme à l'indicatif. Mais devant les pronoms *en* et *y* (lorsqu'ils sont compléments du verbe à l'impératif), on ajoute un `-s` et on fait la liaison. Il en est de même pour les quelques verbes du troisième groupe dont l'impératif singulier est en `-e`.

> Parle de ton expérience. Parles-en. [paʁl.z‿ɑ̃]
>   Pense à ton rendez-vous. Penses-y. [pɑ̃s.z‿i]
>   Cueille des fleurs. Cueilles-en. [kœj.z‿ɑ̃]

La [BDL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=4203) signale quelques cas particuliers :

> Va en acheter. *(“en” est complément de “acheter” et non de “va”, donc pas de `s`)*
>   Laisses-en sortir une. *(“en” est complément de “sortir”, mais “laisser” est une sorte d'auxiliaire, et du coup on met quand même un `s`)*
>   Travaille en silence. *(“en” est une préposition, donc pas de `s`)*

[L'origine des formes de l'impératif](http://monsu.desiderio.free.fr/curiosites/imperatif.html) explique l'historique de ces règles étranges. L'impératif en français ressemble beaucoup à l'indicatif : il est identique sauf au présent singulier pour les verbes du premier groupe, et pour quelques verbes irréguliers. Au premier groupe, l'impératif singulier deuxième personne vient de la forme latine, qui n'a pas non plus d'`s` final : indicatif *amas* → tu aimes, impératif *ama* → aime ! Le `s` devant les pronoms *en* et *y* est en partie euphonique, mais en partie aussi une contamination de l'indicatif, et un ajout de `s` final s'est produit par analogie à l'indicatif sur certains verbes, devenant systématique pour la deuxième personne du singulier à tous les temps et modes alors qu'il ne l'était pas en ancien français.

Comment: À noter que les formes de la deuxième personne du singulier au présent (qui ont le s graphique) ne font jamais liaison en français actuel...